# Another email program like Netscape 7.2

Tags: email

I was happy for years with the email part of Netscape 7.2. I kept a downloaded version of Netscape 7.2 on CD just so I could always put it on my next PC, and did every couple of years.

But it crashed a year ago on my current PC running on MicroSoft XP. I have tried Gmail, Yahoo mail and AOL mail. I hate that none of them are as friendly and versatile as Netscape was before AOL gobbled them up.

For months now I have been using Windows Live Hotmail. Tonight I wanted to create a "List" of several email addresses that I could forward things to with a click. Cannot figure out how.

Soooo, HELP! I want my easy email life back. What program do I go to?

Answer (score 3):

The modern incarnation of Netscape Messenger is [Thunderbird](http://www.mozillamessaging.com/en-US/thunderbird/).

Comment: I second this. Thunderbird will be able to import your Netscape mail folder as well.

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for an integrated suite like Netscape 7.2 used to be, you can also use [Seamonkey](http://www.seamonkey-project.org/)

Comment: +1 Seamonkey is basically a new version of Netscape.